# Split column value using delimiter and insert into different table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have one table with only one column.  That one column contains strings with comma-delimited values.  I am trying to select each string from the table > split the string by the comma's > and then insert the results into a different table.

My first table look like this:

```
DataString
abc,def,gh,i,jkl
mnop,qr,stu,v,wxyz
```

I would like the data to look like this:

```
Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
abc       def     gh      i      jkl
mnop      qr      stu     v      wxyz
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
DECLARE @valueList varchar(100)
DECLARE @pos INT
DECLARE @len INT
DECLARE @value varchar(100)
Select @valueList = DataString from [dbo].[rawdata]


set @pos = 0
set @len = 0

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @valueList, @pos+1)>0
BEGIN
    set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @valueList, @pos+1) - @pos
    set @value = SUBSTRING(@valueList, @pos, @len)

    insert into [dbo].[tempTable] (Value1) Values (@value)    

    set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @valueList, @pos+@len) +1
END
```

I am having two problems with this code.

Problem 1:
- my select statement to pull in the column DataString into the variable @valueList is only pulling the last row in the table instead of selecting all of them.

Problem 2:
- my insert into statement can only insert the values as new rows into the table.  I cant figure out how to enter the values into their corresponding columns.

Any help on how to fix either of my problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need some sort of unique identifier for each row (e.g. assign each row a row number), then split each row with a standard split function (or use your own) and pivot the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your first issue is that assigning a variable to a column like that in a table is only going to pull one row from that column in table. If you want to loop through each row in a column like you're currently doing, you would need to use a `CURSOR` or some variant like that to go through each row.

The second issue you have is that your while statement is incorrect. You're missing the last value from it because you stop when there are no more commas in your datastring. There are no more commas at the last value, so it skips the last value. There's a way around this using your current method, but I would recommend an alternative method of splitting your string.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (datastring VARCHAR(4000));
INSERT @myTable(datastring)
VALUES ('abc,def,gh,i,jkl'),('mnop,qr,stu,v,wxyz');

DECLARE @valueList VARCHAR(4000) = '', @i INT = 1, @pos INT = 0, @len INT = 0, @value VARCHAR(100) = '';
IF OBJECT_ID('tempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tempTable;
CREATE TABLE tempTable (OriginalDataString VARCHAR(4000), stringVal VARCHAR(255), valNum INT);

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
SELECT datastring
FROM @myTable;

OPEN curs;
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @valueList;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SELECT @pos = 0, @len = 0, @i = 1;
    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @len = ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @valueList, @pos+1), 0) - @pos, LEN(@valueList));
        SET @value = SUBSTRING(@valueList, @pos, @len);

        INSERT tempTable(OriginalDataString, stringVal, valNum)
        VALUES (@valueList, @value, @i);

        IF CHARINDEX(',', @valueList, @pos+1) = 0
            BREAK;

        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @valueList, @pos+@len) + 1;
        SET @i += 1;
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @valueList;
END
CLOSE curs;
DEALLOCATE curs;

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN valNum = 1 THEN stringVal END) val1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN valNum = 2 THEN stringVal END) val2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN valNum = 3 THEN stringVal END) val3
     , MAX(CASE WHEN valNum = 4 THEN stringVal END) val4
     , MAX(CASE WHEN valNum = 5 THEN stringVal END) val5
FROM tempTable
GROUP BY OriginalDataString;
```

This uses a cursor to get each datastring in your table, puts each value in a cursor, loops through them to get the value (the loop breaks when you reach the end of the string) and then selects val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 from the resulting table.

But, rather than using a cursor and a while loop, I would recommend the much simpler use of a recursive CTE (or even better, a split function you already have built in).

For example,

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (datastring VARCHAR(4000));
INSERT @myTable(datastring)
VALUES ('abc,def,gh,i,jkl'),('mnop,qr,stu,v,wxyz');

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT datastring
         , SUBSTRING(datastring, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', datastring), 0) - 1, LEN(datastring))) sString
         , NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', datastring), 0) cIndex
         , 1 Lvl
    FROM @myTable T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT datastring
         , SUBSTRING(datastring, cIndex + 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', datastring, cIndex + 1), 0) - 1 - cIndex, LEN(datastring)))
         , NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', datastring, cIndex + 1), 0)
         , Lvl + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE cIndex IS NOT NULL)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Lvl = 1 THEN sString END) val1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Lvl = 2 THEN sString END) val2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Lvl = 3 THEN sString END) val3
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Lvl = 4 THEN sString END) val4
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Lvl = 5 THEN sString END) val5
     --, datastring OriginalDataString
FROM CTE
GROUP BY datastring;
```

Comment: This helped so much!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable table (DataString varchar(250))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('abc,def,gh,i,jkl'),
('mnop,qr,stu,v,wxyz')

Select A.*
      ,Value1=B.Pos1
      ,Value2=B.Pos2
      ,Value3=B.Pos3
      ,Value4=B.Pos4
      ,Value5=B.Pos5
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row](A.DataString,',')) B
```

Returns

```
DataString          Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
abc,def,gh,i,jkl    abc     def     gh      i       jkl
mnop,qr,stu,v,wxyz  mnop    qr      stu     v       wxyz
```

Then UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('John Cappelletti',' ')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('id26,id46|id658,id967','|')

Returns Table 

As

Return (
    SELECT Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(250)')
          ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(250)')
    FROM (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
)
```